# Showing that the number of primes between $n$ and $2n$ only increases as $n$ increases

Tags: number-theory

How can we show that the number of primes between $n$ and $2n$ only increases as $n$ increases?

I also want to prove that the number of primes between $\frac{n^2}{2}$ and $n^2$ only increases as $n$ increases if $n \ge 10$. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: FYI if someone answered your original question but you then realized you have a more interesting question, it's [considered better practice](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23033/can-i-edit-a-question-making-it-more-specific-then-change-the-accepted-answer) to ask a new question rather than changing the existing one.  That way, @TonyK's work won't be wasted, and anyone who finds this question in the future will see an answer that addresses it as stated.

Comment: Sorry think I'll do that then

Comment: By "new question" we meant go back to the home page and click the "Ask Question" button again. I hope that works, especially since your first question is already marked as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to be more careful with statements like that! Do you mean $n\le p\le 2n$, or $n<p<2n$?

The former is false because there are three primes $p$ with $7\le p\le 14$, but only two with $8\le p\le 16$. The latter is false because there are two primes $p$ with $4<p<8$, but only one with $5<p<10$.

The number of such primes does indeed tend to infinity with $n$, as a consequence of the [Prime Number Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem); but your claim ("only gets larger") is stronger than that.

Comment: Ah yes Im realizing that was a wrong assumption on my part, thanks for the clarification

Comment: @DaveConkers You can wait a bit, but as you already have at least one perfectly good answer (this one), I would recommend accepting an answer at some point, maybe 24 hours after you first asked the question. You can still ask the follow-up question in the meantime.

Comment: ok i see thanks